# Don't remove file from repo when is not in local

Tags: git

I'm using Hugo to generate a static website. I have two repos, one with the source of the web, and other with the content generated by Hugo, both hosted in Github.

In the source one I'm using CI to deploy the generated files to the other repos, while in the other I'm using Github pages with a custom domain.

The problem is that every time the script is executes, it deletes the `CNAME` file for using custom domains.

Here is the script:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd ./public

git init
git remote add upstream "https://github.com/user/my-repo.git"
git fetch upstream
git reset upstream/master
git add -A .
git commit -m "web updated"
git push -q upstream HEAD:master
```

I took it from [here](https://github.com/hypriot/blog/blob/master/update_github_pages.sh).

How can I avoid to delete the `CNAME` file?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First:** Make sure CNAME file exists in your **public** folder before running the script.

**Second:** You are doing `reset` your **public** folder with *upstream/master* by `git reset upstream/master` command. So, if CNAME file does not exist in your *upstream/master* then it should be deleted.

Here, I updated the script, see if it works!

```
#!/bin/bash
cd ./public

git init
git remote add upstream "https://github.com/user/my-repo.git"
git fetch upstream
git add -A .
git commit -m "web updated"
git push -q -f upstream HEAD:master
```